# iOS read files from external accessory

Tags: ios, file-io, filesystems

I understand that Apple allows you to develop applications that use an external accessory.

How can you read and write files with this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you want to write the files?

First, you have to go through the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502) for ExternalAccessory framework.